# Combinations Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to achieve an algorithm.

I will get straight into it just say I have 3 boxes

a) 8 x 4
b) 4 x 4 
c) 2 x 4

I want to see how many combinations using the 3 boxes I can get trying to wrap them around another box.

So just say I have a box 16 x 8 I could have a combination like

```
  b-a-a-b         a a-a a       a-a-a
  a     a     OR  a a-a a  OR   c    c
  b-a-a-b                       b    b
                                c    c
                                a-a-a
```

so if the are connected using ' - ' it mean they are placed horizontally if not they are placed vertically.

SO basically you end up with a box wrapped in boxes.

Comment: are you trying to solve multi-dimensional https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: What seems most important is simply looking at the distinct set of edge lengths (2, 4, and 8 in your example), and finding the permutations you can lay them around the circumference of the target box. Then, you can map the edge lengths to the three source boxes (which will create additional permutations when more than one box has the same edge length - i.e. there are 3 boxes you can map to edge length 4).

Comment: A further simplification is that you only have to solve for two sides of the target if it's not a square, and only one side if it is a square. Then you can use those for the other sides. So in a way, you're just looking for how many ways you can arrange the unique edge lengths of the source rectangles along the length of a side of the target rectangle, and then using that as the basis to calculate the final answer.